# How can I make Outlook 2007 remember my Exchange password?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, passwords, exchange

When I connect to my work Exchange account from my home PC (or from a non-domain connected laptop at work) using Outlook 2007 I am always prompted to re-enter my password for the Exchange server.  After that I'm prompted - via a different style dialog box - to log into the Sharepoint server.

How can I get Windows (or Outlook) to not prompt me for these?

(The 'remember password' check box doesn't do anything.)

I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's a setting on the Exchange Server that prevents Outlook remembering the password.  Do you have any other accounts that you could test in Outlook?  Hotmail, Gmail etc?  Also what do your co-workers experience?